# Endless load when using method call instead of property for ngFor directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives, ngfor

In my template, I have this code:

```
<a *ngFor="let item of navItems"
   [routerLink]="item.link"
   routerLinkActive="active"
   class="navigation-item"
   [ngClass]="{'enabled': item.enabled}"
>
  <span class="color-{{item.color}}">
    <mat-icon>{{item.icon}}</mat-icon>
  </span>
  <div class="label">{{item.label}}</div>
</a>
```

where `navItems` is an array in my component:

```
navItems: NavItem[] = [
  {
    link: 'link1', label: 'Label 1', icon: 'thumb_up', color: 'green', enabled: true
  },
  {
    link: 'link2', label: 'Label 2', icon: 'thumb_down', color: 'red', enabled: true
  },
  {
    link: 'link3', label: 'Label 3', icon: 'insert_drive_file', color: 'blue', enabled: true
  },
  {
    link: 'link4', label: 'Label 4', icon: 'note_add', color: 'blue', enabled: true
  },
];
```

This works just fine. Now, I need to change this so that the navItems can change dynamically. I tried just converting the `navItems` property to a getter like this:

```
get navItems(): NavItem[] {
  return [
    {
      link: 'link1', label: 'Label 1', icon: 'thumb_up', color: 'green', enabled: true
    },
    {
      link: 'link2', label: 'Label 2', icon: 'thumb_down', color: 'red', enabled: true
    },
    {
      link: 'link3', label: 'Label 3', icon: 'insert_drive_file', color: 'blue', enabled: true
    },
    {
      link: 'link4', label: 'Label 4', icon: 'note_add', color: 'blue', enabled: true
    },
  ];
}
```

As soon as I do that, however, the browser tab gets caught in an endless loading loop upon loading the component and has to be killed via the task manager - I get no console output, nothing.

I also tried using an ordinary method call instead of a getter to provide the array, same result

The array I'm returning is composed of just plain objects with directly assigned string and boolean literals, so no further calls happen there, so it's unlikely that it's simply that a recursive loop that slipped by me.

Am I doing something wrong? Can't you use method calls / getters to provide the items of an ngFor directive?

Comment: Yes, you can use getters or method calls to provide the items for an `ngFor` loop, as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-2-hidc4r). Something else must be going on; you will have to show us more of your code.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Thanks the confirmation that this should generally work - I've added more code to the question, does this give any more insight?

Comment: Do you also use `navItems` in other parts of you code? For example, in [life cycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) (e.g. `ngAfterViewInit`).

Comment: @ConnorsFan No I don't, this is the only usage so far.

Comment: Does it need to be a getter or method at all? If you modify the original collection, doesn't the UI update to reflect the changes?

Comment: @Slicc That might work, but would introduce state I'll need to change from somewhere else, which I would ideally like to avoid when the collection can just be calculated on the fly without side effects. And as the other commenter has said, this should be possible, and the fact that it doesn't work implies that I have something set up wrong, which I would like to correct regardless of the practical solution to this problem.

Comment: OK, if you are using a getter/method instead of the collection, do you not need to bind to navItems() rather than navItem?

Comment: @Slicc I'm binding to `navItems`, which is the syntax to access the value of the getter. Binding to `navItems()` does not compile unless I actually make it a method instead of a getter, but even then I get the same result.

Comment: Probably a typo, but icon: insert_drive_file' is missing a quote?

Comment: @Slicc Yes you're right, that's just a typo. Fixed it

Comment: Bit strange, but if I remove: routerLinkActive="active", it works in my app, if I leave it, then it fails. Is it possible that this is changing the underlying collection and causing a vicious loop?

Comment: If I change it to: [attr.routerLinkActive]="i === 0 ? 'active' : null" it seems to work fine then

Comment: Using attr.routerLinkActive is nonsense since that's not using the directive anymore at all. routerLinkActive has had a few fixes regarding infinite loops (its easy to Google that), so the Angular version you're using matters here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, when i used, the trackBy then it resolved the issue

> In html file

```
<a *ngFor="let item of navItems; trackBy: trackByFn" [routerLink]="item.link" routerLinkActive="active"
class="navigation-item"
[ngClass]="{'enabled': item.enabled}"
>
<span class="color-{{item.color}}">
 <mat-icon>{{item.icon}}</mat-icon>
</span>
<div class="label">{{item.label}}</div>
</a>
```

In ts file

```
export class AppComponent {
   trackByFn(index,item){
     console.log(index,"n:",item);
     return index;
   }
  get navItems(): NavItem[] {
    return [
      {
        link: 'link1', label: 'Label 1', icon: 'thumb_up', color: 'green', enabled: true
      },
      {
        link: 'link2', label: 'Label 2', icon: 'thumb_down', color: 'red', enabled: true
      },
      {
        link: 'link3', label: 'Label 3', icon: 'insert_drive_file', color: 'blue', enabled: true
      },
      {
        link: 'link4', label: 'Label 4', icon: 'note_add', color: 'blue', enabled: true
      },
    ];
  }
}
class NavItem {
  link;
   label;
    icon;
     color;
     enabled;
}
```

Note:

case-1 : without routerlinkactive[rla] directive and trackBy works fine

case-2 : with rla and trackBy works fine

case-3 : with rla and without trackBy, --> Loop

> Here, RouterLinkActive directive implements [AfterContentInit,and
>   others] inside this AfterContentInit there is a method call
>   update()...which is responsible for having this continuous loops.. I
>   believe that, when the method returns the array..first the elements
>   will get created and then the directive starts acting upon it.. [FYI:
>   When update() was commented out and with out trackBy ,this too works
>   fine as it can't excute the hook methods.]

If you observe the method call navItems , # of method calls = # of items in array.
Each time the array was returned, it renders the those values and  directives will act upon the existing elements and the directives are having hooks[AfterContentInit,onDestroy] which are responsible for adding class the elements and destroying.

> Hence in the absence of trackBy, on each method return , elements will
>   be created and directives will be acting on it by attaching hooks to
>   it  on the next method call again, they will be consider new , and the
>   directives will do the same , but destroys the previous elements..
>   this way it is going in the loop...

Hope this helps!!!

Ref: https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5

Ref:  Creating CustomRouterLinkActive for debugging by using the source from https://github.com/angular/angular

Comment: As trackBy helps in rendering the new values instead of building the entire array of values.Example:even if you pass the new array(having same values as old )...if we don't use trackBy then entire values get rendered again..

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem here is that when you had the array in an instance variable, the array was always the same. I mean, every time Angular tried to detect changes, it detected that the array was the same, so it didn't perform further actions.

However, once you changed the instance variable to a getter, you are returning a new array every time navItems is called. In this case, every time Angular does change detection, it founds a different value. It doesn't matter that conceptually, the items are the same. The arrays are different objects.

I mean, before:

```
// if comp is an instance of your component:
const a = comp.navItems;
const b = comp.navItems;
console.log(a === b); // true. a and b are pointers to the same object.
```

but after your change:

```
const a = comp.navItems; // assigning a the return value of a func!
const b = comp.navItems: // assigninb b the return of a NEW call of a func
console.log(a === b); // false. Two arrays were created here. Two objects.
```

To avoid this issue, you should use trackByFunction, as suggested above. This way only the new/modified items would get rendered again. You also shouldn't return a new array every time, ONLY when the data really has changed. If you still want to construct the array dinamically in the getter, consider using ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush in your component, and then use ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck() to indicate that the component data has changed and it should be checked during change detection. If you don't do this, Angular will never rerender the component except if any of its Input properties change.